# How to row number in SQL Server with counter number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have data

```
NoUrut| Nama
1       PSX
1       GE
1       SX
2       SZ
2       GEX
2       HT
```

how to get output like this with row number

```
Rownum | NoUrut| Nama
 1        1       PSX
 2        1       GE
 3        1       SX
 1        2       SZ
 2        2       GEX
 3        2       HT
```

thank's before

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate. And you must have put literally zero effort into searching for this yourself.

Comment: edit the question add some more sample data and adjust the o/p accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by NoUrut order by (SELECT 0)) as Rownum,
       NoUrut,Nama
FROM Table1;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Rownum  NoUrut  Nama
1        1      PSX
2        1      GE
3        1      SX
1        2      SZ
2        2      GEX
3        2      HT
```

Link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2227b/3

Since You don't want to give `order by` on any column so use `SELECT 0` in order by clause to accomplish the above result.

Comment: @mahfudin foed Try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function

```
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by NoUrut order by NoUrut) as Rownum 
from table t;
```

Comment: Yes I have do it, But row number is counter until the last

Comment: @mahfudinfoed what does that mean?